# How to remove red curvy lines in Python code in Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, ide, sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Can anyone tell me how to remove these red curvy lines in Python code in Sublime Text 3. They are kinda annoying and I can't get the solution anywhere..
I am attaching the screenshot of what I am talking about

[image]

Comment: What does warning say when hovered over ?

Comment: that's the problem, nothing shows up when I hover over them. 
I don't know why these lines and warnings are showing up..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

- On the right bottom "Tab Size: 4" click it, and select "Convert Indentation to Tabs"

Or Backup and reset Sublime text to its default setting

- https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/revert.html
- https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/revert.html

Comment: The "Convert Indentation to Tabs" didn't work.
I am currently on Linux not windows. Where can I find that file in Linux ?